# Issue with averaging images in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, average

when I try to average a folder of jpeg matlab images, all that I get is a blank image. I've gone over my code a million times, and I don't know where I'm 
going wrong. (also I know I hard coded some of the numbers but that just because I wanted it to take a specific folder and I've double checked those a million times, they're right.)

```
            %takes all the images in a folder and averages their values 
    %opens folder
    function avg_image = average_images()
    folder_name = uigetdir;  
    folder_directory = dir(folder_name); 
    filename = folder_directory(3).name;
    len = length(folder_directory); 
    org_image = imread(filename); 
    sum_image = org_image; 
    %adds files together 
    for i = 4:len 
         filename = folder_directory(i).name;  
    org_image = imread(filename); 
    sum_image = sum_image + org_image;  
    end 
   %calculates average
   avg_image = sum_image/(len-2); 
   %saves average as a fits file and displays it 
   imwrite(avg_image, 'averagefile.jpg'); 
   read_image = imread('averagefile.jpg');
   imshow(read_image) 
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are reading in the JPGs as uint8 (default) and then doing math with the images as matrices of uint8's (0-255 integers).  As you read in org_image, above and inside the for loop, cast the result as a double:`org_image = double(imread(filename))`.  After you're done with the averaging, you need to cast it back, `avg_image = uint8(sum_image/(len-2))`.

When you do math with uint8's, divisions are messy since decimals are truncated.  4 divided by 8 when both are doubles gives you 0.5.  When both are integers, you get 0.